# How to edit data in specific columns by a click on it in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, click, edit

I want to **update cells** in **selected columns** in **gridview**. Edit function must work when I ***click on a cell*** belong to that selected column. Is it possible to do? I have tried to search examples over the internet. But all of them are not in the way i expect to do. If anyone knows how to do please let me know.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:20px;" 
                    onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing1">
                    <%--OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing--%>
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="chdrnum" HeaderText="Client Num" 
                            ItemStyle-Width="100" ReadOnly="True" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CCDATE" HeaderText="Risk Date" ItemStyle-Width="100" 
                            ReadOnly="True" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SUMIN" HeaderText="Sum Assured" 
                            ItemStyle-Width="100" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SINSTAMT06" HeaderText="Premiums" 
                            ItemStyle-Width="100" ReadOnly="True" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PTDATE" HeaderText="Next Due Date" 
                            ItemStyle-Width="100" ReadOnly="True" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Surrender Value" 
                            ItemStyle-Width="100" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Loan Outstanding" 
                            ItemStyle-Width="100" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Age Admitted" ItemStyle-Width="100" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <%--                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdate" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="OnCancel" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3AC0F2" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds=db.getClientPolicies(polNo);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
     GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
md1.Show();
```

Comment: you want Inline Editing inside gridview  ?

Comment: Yes, But only one column should allow editing. All the other columns should not allow. Also it should be happen when click on the cell

Comment: I've removed my solution. I didn't see the asp.net tag, thought you were using winforms.

Comment: Ok so can you help me with this?